# Changing attributes of HTML element in server-side code in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want to be able to access and modify attributes of HTML elements of a page in my server side code (I am using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages 6.0).

For example: a `.cshtml` file, I have a simple element like this:

```
<div class="mb-3 mt-3">
    <label asp-for="User.firstname" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
    <input asp-for="User.firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

How do I access & change attributes of the above `<input>` element inside the `OnGet` or `OnPost` server-side methods?

I need to do so as I want to add a class to that `<input>` element, or make it read-only (depending on certain conditions in my server code).

In older versions of .NET, I believe this was possible by giving an HTML element an ID, and writing runat="server". Then, one could access the element in the code-behind via its ID and change its attributes. How is this done now in Razor Pages?
Should I not be able to do the same because of the asp-for tag helper which I used inn my code above? But how?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @mauro.ian, any update here?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve sending Value to the server with

This at razor page:

```
   <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Type title here.." />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
```

This at Model Page

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string title)
        {
           //do your stuff 
        }
```

Put breakpoint at public async Taks and viola.

I believe this should do the trick. You can change it for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
}
```

**Page(.cshtml file)**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">

    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
        <label asp-for="User.firstname" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="User.firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>

</form>
```

**PageModel(.cshtml.cs file)**

1.For model binding of the element, **one way** is that you can use `[BindProperty]`:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        //do your stuff.....
    }
}
```

[image]

2.**The second way** is that you can add parameters like below:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    public User User { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public void OnPost(User User)
    {

    }
    
}
```

[image]